# How can I get id of clicked button for this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

[image]

I have scenario like this, I'm having some bosxes here, I have written likes this

```
<div class="divlocker">
```

I have buttons like Q1,Q2,Q3...etc upto Q12. When clicking any button corresponding box in above position must change there text. how can I add this ?

This is my button code

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="btnQ3" onclick="OpenBox()">Q3</button>
```

I need to call an ajax when clicking on any button. how can i do that ?[image]

Comment: I believe your question is confusing, could you maybe try to explain it better or try to remove complexity and provide minimal example?

Answer (score 1):

In your OpenBox() function, you should be able to access an object whose name is "event". Using that object will make you able to retrieve the id of the button that was clicked.

Try to console.log(event) in the body of your function if you're unsure about what you should do

Comment: why not directly using $(this).attr("id");?

Comment: Yes, this is what I'd do if I had to use jQuery, it's basically the same thing

Comment: yeah - the question is tagged with jquery - so we use it ;-)